# 2 div covering each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

what i have is this:

```
<style>
#main{position:relative; width:600px; height: 600px;}
#cover{position:absolute}
#image{position:absolute}
</style>

<div id="main">
   <div id="cover"><img src="template.png" /></div>
   <div id="image"><img src="user.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

what i need is to be able to move the user image around, but it will be covered with the cover div that will mask my other one. is there a way for that?

in addition i need to know if it is possible to have the div#cover only with the png file in it but where the size of the image is not as big as the id#main so the rest of the cover div will be background color white - without getting a white color in the image area?

**update:**
i want to have a layer (div#cover) that will cover another layer(div#image). in the first one i will have a circle  that the inner of it is transparent and the outer is white so i will be able to see the bottom layer img within the cover layer
i will have jquery dragable to the second layer but it wont work becuase of the top layer that will block it from being draged with the mouse

**my question was - is it possible to have the bottom layer to be draged when there is a cover layer on top of it?**

Comment: very hard to understand, create a jsfiddle demo of this please

Comment: Please, can you try being more explicit and clear ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this markup? As in, what will this be used for? I think I get what you're trying to do, but I don't think this will work...

Comment: i want to make and upload of a photo and the user puts it within the cover in order to get his picture (face for example) within the cover of the head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very difficult to answer a question one can't understand.

How to make a image/container draggable : http://jsfiddle.net/cNtfM/

Using jQuery/jQuery-UI is the easiest way in my eyes.

Your CoverImage will be above the other image coz you are writing it to the page before the main image. [renders from top to bottom]

**I have know idea if this answers your question.**

Comment: Like Kashiv mentioned, you can use z-index to properly set the layer level of your items.

Comment: got me very close to the solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cover a div with another div, use z-index property:

```
#cover{position:absolute;z-index:101;}
#image{position:absolute;z-index:100;}
```

I can't answer to your second question, because I don't understand it. Can you explain it more precisely?

Edit: after your edit I understand what you mean: **you want to move an image that is under some kind of cropping frame**. I think it's more complicated than using 2 divs and CSS...

Comment: If you want to drag your divs, use jQuery (as mentioned by @Marc Uberstein)